# Looking for literature on $y'''-xy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I recently came across the differential equation

$y'''(x) - xy = 0$, but cannot find anything online about it. It seems simple enough that people must have already studied it. Could anyone provide a name for the equation and/or some references on its behaviors?

Comment: Found it on eqworld http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0412.pdf

Comment: This is a special case of the [hypergeometric differential equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricDifferentialEquation.html). Its solutions, the [Generalized Hypergeometric Functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html) have some nice known properties.